# During the HTTPS connection, who raises the request to close the connections

Tags: tcp, https

Anyone can tell me who, during the HTTPS connection process, raises the request to close the connections, browser or server?

And in addition, after the connection was closed, how about the encryption key? When will the key expire?

Comment: Be aware, this is not a Q & A forum. It is a help forum for techies trying to achieve something.
Before posting a question on this forum, try to do some basic research of your own. Have you tried to Google the subject? If so, what have you learned so far? What confuses you or is missing from on-line sources?

Answer (score 2):

Either peer can close the connection.

The key expires with the SSL session. NB not the HTTP session.